# ¿Se debe usar mayúscula para una palabra entre comillas al inicio de una oración?

Tags: ortografía, uso-de-mayúsculas

En esta:

https://spanish.stackexchange.com/posts/27796/revisions

y otras respuestas anteriores, toda vez que utilicé una palabra entre comillas al inicio de oración con minúscula, la palabra fue editada por algún colega del sitio.

Mi opinión es que una palabra (no una cita) entrecomillada está siendo utilizada metalingüísticamente y, por lo tanto, debería mantenerse en minúscula, al igual que las entradas del diccionario.

Así, del mismo modo que el diccionario dice:

> lindura
>   1. f. Cualidad de lindo.
>   2. f. Persona o cosa linda.

(véase que "lindura" está en minúscula), mi opinión es que es correcto escribir:

> "lindura" es el sustantivo abstracto correspondiente al adjetivo "lindo", o bien:
>
> La palabra "lindura" denota la cualidad de lindo.

Mi pregunta es: ¿cuál es la norma que indica que, **utilizada metalingüísticamente**, es decir, no para hablar de la lindura sino de la palabra "lindura" (o cualquier otra), una palabra debe llevar mayúscula inicial al comienzo de una oración?

Comment: Tienes toda la razón cuando dices: "Mi opinión es que una palabra (no una cita) entrecomillada está siendo utilizada metalingüísticamente y, por lo tanto, debería mantenerse en minúscula, al igual que las entradas del diccionario." Estoy un poco harta de los votos abajo [?] para algo que sería obvio para cualquier lingüísta. La respuesta de Charlie cita la RAE, y la RAE ****no trata este caso preciso****. Valdría la pena preguntárselo a la RAE.

Comment: Gracias por tu apoyo. En español diríamos "voto negativo" para *downvote* :).

Comment: Gracias. El argumento principal sería que "lindura" está en el diccionario, y "Lindura", no. La RAE no habla del caso. Es bastante fuera de lo común...al ponerle una mayúscula, el sentido cambia.

Comment: La respuesta dada en blog de la RAE no lleva en cuenta tu pregunta por completo. Responde como se fuera cualquier voz en un/el diccionario. No lleva en cuenta el aspecto meta.

Answer (score 4):

En la *Ortografía* de la RAE, en el capítulo 4 se habla sobre el uso de mayúsculas y minúsculas. El [apartado 4.1](http://aplica.rae.es/orweb/cgi-bin/v.cgi?i=fMjXphPfzgOkkzbs) dice (negritas mías):

> Se escriben con mayúscula inicial exigida por la puntuación las palabras siguientes:
>
> 4.1.1.1 La primera palabra de un escrito o la que aparece después de un punto, **independientemente de que pueda estar precedida de** un signo de apertura de paréntesis, **comillas**, interrogación o exclamación.

Y cita como excepción:

> El único caso en el que la primera palabra de un texto o enunciado puede aparecer escrita con minúscula inicial se da cuando dicha palabra va precedida de los puntos suspensivos que indican, en la reproducción de una cita, que el fragmento citado no inicia enunciado en el texto original: *«... y los sueños, sueños son», como afirmaba Segismundo en uno de los dos famosos monólogos de* La vida es sueño, *de Calderón de la Barca*; pero si se prescinde de los puntos suspensivos, la primera palabra se escribe, como es preceptivo, con mayúscula: *«Y los sueños, sueños son», como afirmaba Segismundo en uno de los dos famosos monólogos de* La vida es sueño, *de Calderón de la Barca*.

Entiendo que el caso del diccionario es un caso especial. En las palabras del diccionario no se escriben frases, solo son enumeraciones de palabras, y dicha enumeración va con minúscula inicial para distinguir las palabras que siempre deben ir con mayúscula inicial de las que no. Por ejemplo, la palabra "Estocolmo" está presente en el diccionario:

> **[Estocolmo](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Gu9qUA4)**
>
> síndrome de Estocolmo

y va con mayúscula en la definición para indicar que siempre se usa así. En otras definiciones te pueden indicar "con mayúscula inicial en acepciones tal y cual". Pero me estoy desviando del tema. Tal vez podrías acogerte a esto mismo de "evitar hacer creer que la palabra a la que aludes se escriba siempre con mayúscula inicial" para argumentar que en tu ejemplo "lindura" se escriba con minúscula a pesar de estar al principio de la frase. Para estos casos la RAE dice, por poner un ejemplo (negritas mías de nuevo):

> Las siglas indicativas de los protocolos de acceso a las páginas electrónicas (*http, https*) y la que antecede al nombre de un dominio en Internet (*www*) se escriben siempre con minúsculas en las direcciones electrónicas: *http://www.asale.org*. Puesto que no pueden escribirse con mayúscula inicial aun tratándose del primer elemento de un escrito o de un enunciado, **se recomienda evitar que aparezcan en dicha posición**, anteponiéndoles algún otro elemento: *El sitio www.tragalibros.com cuenta con un extenso catálogo de literatura infantil*.

Si nos acogemos a esta recomendación, tu ejemplo quedaría mejor redactado así:

> La voz "lindura" representa el sustantivo abstracto correspondiente al adjetivo "lindo".

Es costumbre de la RAE proponer alternativas en caso de duda o ante casos que bordean las normas establecidas. En todo caso, una vez consultada a la RAE en Twitter su respuesta ha sido [la siguiente](https://twitter.com/RAEinforma/status/1062712964552278016):

> Aunque una voz se emplee metalingüísticamente, si se encuentra a comienzo de enunciado, debe escribirse con mayúscula inicial.

Por tanto, finalmente parece que tu ejemplo debería escribirse así:

> "Lindura" es el sustantivo abstracto correspondiente al adjetivo "lindo".

Comment: la RAE no trata del tema.

Comment: @Lambie ¿En qué te basas para decir esto? Charlie ha copiado textos de la RAE en los que se trata específicamente de este asunto.

Comment: @Gorpik No, la RAE dice que ***hay que evitar de poner direcciones electrónicas en posición inicial***. No dice nada sobre el hecho de poner una palabra entre comillas en posición inicial como como para referirse a su definición. Por favor, léalo otra vez.  Gracias. Tampoco existe una regla al respecto en inglés. O sea: metalingüísticamente.

Comment: @Lambie En los párrafos que copia Charlie podemos leer que el único caso en que se puede empezar un texto con minúscula es cuando se inicia con puntos suspensivos, y que esto incluye el caso en que la primera palabra va precedida de comillas. No puede ser más explícito.

Comment: @Gorpik Es razonable pensar que no se les ocurrió. No creo que dirían que una palabra entre comillas que se define en seguida en una frase llevaría una mayúscula. Es un caso muy especial. Tampoco en inglés. Lo que sí dirían es que se busca otra forma de empezar la frase, eso si.

Comment: @Gustavson Las reglas de la RAE no llevan en cuenta las comillas. Son las comillas que cambian todo.

Comment: Véase pregunta relacionada: https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/5817/18523

Comment: Si pone una mayúscula a un término tal y cual viene en la DRAE y entre comillas, ya no estás citando dicha obra maestra. Para citar términos no hay que poner una mayúscula.

Answer (score -1):

Para mi, la definición de una palabra no necesita mayúscula.

El DRAE no tiene este caso específico.

Pero hay que decir que el caso no se ve mucho.

"hogar" es una palabra con una historia larga.

¿Por qué llevaría mayúscula? No tiene sentido ninguno.

Tienes toda la razón de escribir la frase abajo como la has escrito:

"lindura" es el sustantivo abstracto correspondiente al adjetivo "lindo", o bien:

La palabra "lindura" denota la cualidad de lindo.

[Tengo que fijarme bien para no confundirme con el portugués: maiúscula, ja ja.]

Ejemplo de la DRAE:

diccionario enciclopédico

1. m. diccionario que, además de las palabras comunes de una lengua, contiene nombres propios de destacados personajes, acontecimientos, lugares, etc.

Mi frase:

**"diccionario enciclopédico" es un término en el Dicionario de la lengua española de la Real Academia Española.**

No creo que ningún académico español pusiera una mayúscula en esta frase.
Infelizmente, cuando se hizo la pregunta al académico que se cita no-sé-dónde arriba, la pregunta no fue clara. Pregúntaselo otra vez. Veréis.

¡ Qué disfruteis !

[DRAE definición de diccionario enciclopédico](https://dle.rae.es/?id=DgIqVCc)

Comment: Do you know by any chance of any rule about this matter in English which could help us by analogy?

Comment: ***No existe ninguna indicación de la/en la RAE sobre este caso preciso***. No se suele ver fuera de los contextos lingüísticos y de traducción. La RAE solo da el ejemplo de direcciones electrónicas. Y es por eso que no tengo ninguna regla que se pueda aplicar al caso este.

Comment: @parliamentofowls Estás equivocado/da.

Comment: La RAE cita expresamente "Se escribe con mayúscula inicial la primera palabra de un escrito o la que aparece después de un punto, independientemente de que pueda estar precedida de un signo de comillas". ¿No te parece el caso del ejemplo de @Gustavson?

Comment: Sí la frase de la RAE dice eso y encontrarás la misma "regla" en inglês. Pero la RAE no trata de este asunto. Por el hecho de ser muy poco frecuente y muy especializado. Si se pone en la posición inicial: "Lindura" quiere decir etc." eso automaticamente indica que lindura sempre lleva mayúscula, como es la caso de Estocolmo. Puede ser mejor evitarlo, pero en contextos metalingüísticos, la minúscula es lo que se debe poner. Como soy lingüísta, me lo autorizo yo misma.

Comment: @Lambie ¿has oído alguna vez hablar de la "falacia de autoridad"?

Comment: @Charlie: mark my words: I never said I was an authority. I said: I authorize myself to have this opinion. Not the same thing at all.

Comment: If you say so, but it seems that a higher, royal authority [thinks the opposite](https://twitter.com/RAEinforma/status/1062712964552278016): "Aunque una voz se emplee metalingüísticamente, si se encuentra a comienzo de enunciado, debe escribirse con mayúscula inicial." (RAE on Twitter.)

Comment: I did not say I was an authority. Don't mis-characterize it, please. You should have asked them about a specific example. And you forgot the "entre comillas" perhaps the most important part of the question.

Comment: @Berenguela Si nada funciona, vayamos al sarcasmo, ¿no?

Comment: @Charlie You very conveniently left out the "..." around the word in your question to the RAE. There is no dictionary entry: "Lindura". There is only lindura, lower case.

Comment: @Charlie Have you ever heard of something in quotation marks starting a sentence and being anything other than what is being cited? The answer to this question for a linguist is obvious. In any language. Unless you are citing a proper name in quotation marks, the word would not be in caps. The RAE has no words in caps and they do not ***deal*** with specific metalinguistic usage. That RAE Twitter thing is not our case here: metalinguistic usage of terms that are cited in quotation marks. If you put it in caps, it is no longer a cited term!

Comment: In fact, the RAE gentleman does not answer the question about una voz entre comillas. He just means words listed in a dictionary that are used at the beginning of a sentence. He actually missed the entire point because he did not read the question carefully enough.

Comment: The bad faith here is incredible. Your email message from that gentleman shows that the question was poorly  posed to him. He says: "Aunque una voz se emplee metalingüísticamente" Una citación de término no es "una voz (palabra) empleada metalingüísticamente."